# Sort a List and keep a particular element at end of list after sorting

Tags: c#, linq, list, sorting

I have a list of string containing `"Others"`. I am getting this list for drop down. I am sorting this list alphabetically. But I need `"Others"` always at end of list. I don't want to add this element after sorting which is one solution. Is there any other way to do the same like by using custom comparer of `.Sort()` method. I tried like below but no solution.

```
 public class EOComparer : IComparer<string>
    {
        public int Compare(string x, string y)
        {
            if (x == null)
            {
                if (y == null)
                {
                    // If x is null and y is null, they're
                    // equal. 
                    return 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    // If x is null and y is not null, y
                    // is greater. 
                    return -1;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // If x is not null...
                //
                if (y == null)
                // ...and y is null, x is greater.
                {
                    return 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (x.ToLower().Contains("other"))
                    {
                        return -1;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // If the strings are of equal length,
                        // sort them with ordinary string comparison.
                        //
                        return x.CompareTo(y);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

and calling it as :

```
EOComparer c = new EOComparer();
a.Sort((x, y) => c.Compare(x.OptionValue, y.OptionValue));
             return a;
```

Please help if it is possible.

Comment: add "if y contains 'other' return 1 " too

Comment: Why not use a Dictionary? Put "Others" as key and the sorted list as value

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36058979/360211) is a fine answer, but I thought I would fix your comparer:

Test:

```
[TestCase(new string[0], new string[0])]
[TestCase(new[] { "a" }, new[] { "a" })]
[TestCase(new[] { "a", "b" }, new[] { "a", "b" })]
[TestCase(new[] { "b", "a" }, new[] { "a", "b" })]
[TestCase(new[] {"others"}, new[] {"others"})]
[TestCase(new[] {"a", "others"}, new[] {"a", "others"})]
[TestCase(new[] {"others", "a"}, new[] {"a", "others"})]
[TestCase(new[] {"others", "x"}, new[] {"x", "others"})]
[TestCase(new[] {"Others", "x"}, new[] {"x", "Others"})]
[TestCase(new[] { "othersz", "others" }, new[] { "othersz", "others" })]
[TestCase(new[] {"z", "y", "x", "others", "b", "a", "c"},
          new[] {"a", "b", "c", "x", "y", "z", "others"})]
public void CanSortWithOthersAtEnd(string[] input, string[] expectedSorted)
{
    var a = new List<string>(input);
    var c = new EOComparer();
    a.Sort(c.Compare);
    CollectionAssert.AreEqual(expectedSorted, a);
}
```

Comparer:

```
public sealed class EOComparer : IComparer<string>
{
    public int Compare(string x, string y)
    {
        if (IsOthers(x)) return 1;
        if (IsOthers(y)) return -1;
        return string.Compare(x, y, StringComparison.Ordinal);
    }

    private static bool IsOthers(string str)
    {
        return string.Compare(str, "others", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0;
    }
}
```

Note how my use of `string.Compare` avoids all `== null` checks. And how `StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase` avoids `.ToLower()` and thus avoids creating copies of the strings.

Comment: This is a better solution because it avoids making a temporary copy of the list (which the Linq solution will do). Although if the list is small, this hardly matters.

Answer (score 31):

Use this logic

```
List<string> l = new List<string>{ "z", "y", "x", "other", "b", "a", "c" };
var result = l.OrderBy(i => i == "other").ThenBy(i => i).ToList();
result.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
```

Output:

> a b c x y z other

If you want `other` to be on top of the list make it

```
var result = l.OrderBy(i => i != "other").ThenBy(i => i).ToList();
```

Output:

> other a b c x y z

Comment: Actually i had already tried this , but didn't work. My list is a list of object having id and value and i tried like "l.OrderBy(i => i.Value != "other").ThenBy(i => i.value).ToList();" but it was not working for me

Comment: Was it not sorted at all or was `other` not appearing at the right place?

Comment: i tried with != and == operator but "other" was not appearing on either end.. result was same as of normal orderby(value)

Comment: may be a bit late here but: l.OrderByDescending(i=>i.Equals("other").ThenBy(i=>i).ToList() worked for me to make other to be on top.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we have objects with the following list items.

object.Text = "a"
object.Value = 1

object.Text = "b"
object.Value = 2

object.Text = "other"
object.Value = 3

object.Text = "c"
object.Value = 4

the following works for me:

var oList = objects.OrderBy(i => i.Text != "other").ThenBy(i => i.Text);